# Find invalid dates in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

I have a 300.000 rows table; one of the columns is a varchar() but it really contains a date xx/xx/xxxx or x/x/xxxx or similar. But executing the following test yields an error:

```
SELECT CAST(MyDate as Datetime) FROM MyTable
```

The problem is that it doesn’t tell me in which row…

I have executed a series of “manual” updates by trial an error and performed simple updates to fix those, but there’s got to be some weird values that need to either be deleted or fixed.

For example I performed a simple test that fixed about 40 rows:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyDate = REPLACE(MyDate, '/000','/200') FROM MyTable WHERE MyDate like ('%/000%’)
UPDATE MyTable SET MyDate = REPLACE(MyDate, '/190','/199') FROM MyTable WHERE MyDate like ('%/190%’)
```

This fixed quite a few weird rows that had dates like 01/01/0003 and such. (Dates range from 1998 to 2010).

However, I’d like to know **which** rows are failing in the above select.

What would be the best way to print those so I can either delete them, edit them or see what to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
SELECT
      *
FROM
      MyTable
WHERE
      ISDATE(MyDate) = 0
```

From the [ISDATE(Transact-SQL) documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) `ISDATE(...)`

> Returns 1 if the expression is a valid datetime value; otherwise, 0.
>
> ISDATE returns 0 if the expression is a [datetime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) value.

Comment: In my case for a nullable field, WHERE ISDATE(MyDate) = 0 AND MyDate IS NOT NULL.

Comment: @Nielsvh Could it be that the type of your column `MyDate` is of type [datetime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try the [`ISDATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) function?

Answer (score 2):

ISDATE doesn't seem to be working always.

the following returns 1 in SQL server 2008 R2
`Select ISDATE('04- December 20')`

But trying to cast the same value to date will fail.
`Select cast('04- December 20' as date)`

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value; otherwise, 0.  

Select cast('04- December 20' as datetime)  
Returns: '2020-12-04 00:00:00.000'      

So its working fine as designed :)

Comment: This caught me, I looked for Isdate(myfield)=1 in a CTE and then in the next CTE tried to find records in a date range.  I was getting the error  cant convert string to a date.... in the 2nd cte i needed to do a casat as @jonas suggests here.

Answer (score 1):

Careful with IsDate.  I have 1 bad record in a table of thousands.  It says 8201-11-30 is a valid date.  IsDate should have a YEAR limitation.

Comment: 8201-11-30 is a valid date since CONVERT(date, '8201-11-30') succeeds. It's also logically valid ... assuming we don't change how we track date in the next 6000 years. A year limit would be application specific ... a validation rule.