# Error when using DateAdd - TSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, dateadd

I have an app that uses a table that has a `varchar` column `[BadColumn]` which is populated by a date in the format `MM/DD/YYYY` or at least that's what most of the rows contain.

I have no control on modifying this table and changing the data type.

I need to report on this data to show rows that are within a week.

Here's my problem:

every time I use something to compare/filter the date I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

So here's what I have tried so far :

1. Tried to create a view with the `[BadColumn]` being converted to a `Date` type column `[NewBadColumn]` and convert the value from the original table to a date type using `Convert(date, BadColumn)`. The view gets populated, but now when I still try to query using `DateADD` or do any date comparisons I get the same error.
2. I have also tried to use `Convert(Date, BadColumn, 105)`, but same problem.
3. I have tried other formats, but still the same issue cannot do a date comparison on that column.

I am not sure which row is throwing the error, how do I find it  and fix this issue.

Thank you for the responses. I have tried using ISDate function to find the bad records.
But I am still getting the same error "**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**"  when I try to use  DateAdd.

Here's the code I am using :

Select t.* 
from 
(Select * from dbo.BadTableName q with (nolock)
where ISDate(BadColumn)=1  and ISDATE(BadColumn) Is Not Null
) t
where t.BadColumn > DATEADD(dd,-2, GetDATE())

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060952/find-invalid-dates-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the column using the `ISDATE()` function. You can do this without creating a view first.

```
IF ISDATE(YourColumn) = 1
DATEADD (datepart , number , YourColumn )
ELSE 'No valid date provided'
```

Comment: I have used ISDate and failed, posted more info in the question

Comment: Have you had a look at the limitations of `ISDATE()` ? It Returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value; otherwise, 0.
ISDATE returns 0 if the expression is a datetime2 value. Dropping the second condition of your subselect should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Look at this other stack over flow question and answer**

[Find invalid dates in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060952/find-invalid-dates-in-sql-server-2008)

You can use the **ISDATE** function to test the individual rows.

Comment: I have used ISDate and failed, posted more info in the question