# can't filter a view (datetype conversion error)

Tags: sql, view

I have a view for which I'm trying to query.

```
Select top 100 Expiration , year(Expiration) from CICPROD.ExpiredLots

--where year(Expiration) = 2017
```

which returns (when I edit out the WHERE part):

```
Expiration  (No column name)
2017-09-10  2017
2021-06-20  2021
2017-01-16  2017
2017-01-04  2017
2017-08-22  2017
2017-01-25  2017
2021-07-18  2021
2017-04-28  2017
2017-09-14  2017
2017-01-04  2017
2010-06-10  2010
2020-04-24  2020
2019-03-03  2019
2020-09-11  2020
2020-06-10  2020
2020-03-26  2020
2020-07-14  2020
2017-05-13  2017
2018-02-16  2018
2015-05-25  2015
2015-08-29  2015
2016-04-04  2016
2017-03-31  2017
2017-03-31  2017
2017-03-31  2017
2015-08-15  2015
2018-02-27  2018
2018-02-16  2018
2016-01-31  2016
2017-03-31  2017
2014-02-01  2014
2018-08-09  2018
2007-08-01  2007
2017-05-27  2017
2020-12-15  2020
2012-03-31  2012
2012-03-22  2012
2016-01-05  2016
2018-01-10  2018
2013-03-05  2013
2015-08-05  2015
2017-11-30  2017
2013-06-12  2013
2019-11-22  2019
2013-04-27  2013
2016-04-17  2016
2018-01-10  2018
2018-02-16  2018
2018-01-10  2018
2018-02-16  2018
2016-04-30  2016
2020-01-05  2020
2016-12-21  2016
2017-11-08  2017
2018-01-10  2018
2014-09-14  2014
2018-01-10  2018
2016-06-25  2016
2014-01-31  2014
2020-03-20  2020
2017-02-15  2017
2016-02-01  2016
2015-08-05  2015
2016-03-24  2016
2013-08-28  2013
2016-09-08  2016
2018-02-16  2018
2014-12-09  2014
2017-08-13  2017
2018-01-10  2018
2016-10-23  2016
2018-02-17  2018
2009-05-28  2009
2017-07-12  2017
2017-03-31  2017
2016-04-23  2016
2015-04-11  2015
2018-01-10  2018
2017-11-17  2017
2018-01-10  2018
2017-11-08  2017
2017-11-08  2017
2017-03-31  2017
2017-03-31  2017
2017-10-02  2017
2011-05-03  2011
2010-12-10  2010
2014-11-14  2014
2017-08-17  2017
2015-06-30  2015
2017-10-12  2017
2016-03-23  2016
2018-05-10  2018
2017-08-17  2017
2017-01-01  2017
2015-12-19  2015
2016-02-28  2016
2018-02-27  2018
2017-07-07  2017
2016-09-08  2016
```

However, when I try to filter the where with column 2 to say 2017, I get the error message:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

But when I tried it with TOP 10, the query WORKED no PROBLEM!!

I checked the length of the field and they're all 10 and have the same format so I'm wondering why this is happening.

Can anyone assist??

Original Query is:

```
Select cast([STOLOTFCY].ITMREF_0 as varchar(20)) as 'Product', 

[ITMMASTER].ITMDES1_0 as 'Desc1',  

[STOLOTFCY].STOFCY_0 as Site, cast([STOLOTFCY].LOT_0 as varchar(30)) as Lot ,

 [STOCK].STA_0 as Status,

( case when isdate([STOLOT].USRFLD1_0) = 0 then null else 

convert(date,[STOLOT].USRFLD1_0,101) end)  as Expiration, 

[STOCK].QTYSTU_0 as 'Total Stk', 

  [ITMMASTER].STU_0 as 'STK', [STOLOTFCY].AVC_0 as 'avgcost' ,

  [STOLOTFCY].AVC_0 * [STOCK].QTYSTU_0 as 'ExtendedValue' , 

  cast([STOLOT].LOTCREDAT_0 as date) as 'Lotcreated', 

  [ITMMASTER].ITMWEI_0 * [STOCK].QTYSTU_0 as 'TotalWgt(Kg)'
 from [CICPROD].[STOLOTFCY] 
inner join [CICPROD].[ITMMASTER] on  [STOLOTFCY].ITMREF_0 = [ITMMASTER].ITMREF_0
inner join [CICPROD].[STOLOT] on [STOLOT].ITMREF_0 = [STOLOTFCY].ITMREF_0 and [STOLOT].LOT_0 = [STOLOTFCY].LOT_0
inner join [CICPROD].[STOCK] on [STOCK].ITMREF_0 = [STOLOTFCY].ITMREF_0 and [STOLOTFCY].STOFCY_0 = [STOCK].STOFCY_0 and [STOCK].LOT_0 =
[STOLOTFCY].LOT_0 and [STOLOTFCY].SLO_0 = [STOCK].SLO_0
where [STOLOTFCY].[AAACUMQTY_0] + [STOLOTFCY].[QQQCUMQTY_0] + [STOLOTFCY].[RRRCUMQTY_0] > 0
```

Comment: Also, when I try to run the isdate() function to see if any values are causing the error throwing, I get this:                                                                     Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type date is invalid for argument 1 of isdate function.

Comment: could you try `Select *, year(Expiration) from CICPROD.ExpiredLots`

Comment: that works, but the filtering doesn't work in the where clause. I'm thinking maybe it's the source code from the view itself but this has been puzzling me all day

Comment: It looks to me that the date is stored as a string and that with that filter applied it's forced to try to evaluate as a date something it didn't have to evaluate as a date previously ... If you remove both the where clause and the top 100, i reckon you'll see errors again. My guess would be a 'date'  such as 2017-04-31 which might pass a quick visual check but isn't a valid date.

Comment: Depending on the flavour of SQL you're using, this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060952/find-invalid-dates-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Thanks for the reply Steve I had a look and tried that , but for some reason SQL-SRV is acting really strange.       I tried this:_select top 2000 * from [CICPROD].[ExpiredLots] where [ExpiredLots].[Expiration] is not null_ and it worked!!, but when I try:_select  * from [CICPROD].[ExpiredLots] where [ExpiredLots].[Expiration] is not null_, I get the error message. I'm honestly so confused as to what is happening I can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you have access to the code for the view? If so, can you post it?

Comment: Just to let you know what I'm thinking, my current 'guess' is that although 'expiration' may be a date-type, perhaps the view itself is converting to that from text. If you could run the kinds of check mentioned in that linked answer against the source for that column in the view rather than against that column itself, i reckon you'd find the problem data.

Comment: updated the post to inlcude the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion via comments i think the following code should help you find the data which is causing the query to fail.

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;
select
[STOLOT].USRFLD1_0, *
from
CICPROD.STOLOT
WHERE
ISDATE([STOLOT].USRFLD1_0)= 0 and [STOLOT].USRFLD1_0 is not null
```

Comment: That code will return your problem records but perhaps also others which aren't problematic. If there are too many we'll need to add steps to compare the output to that when using your default setting for `DATEFORMAT`.

Comment: THANK YOU! Oh my god that ws so frustrating. I found it was ONE line out of 5000 that was causing the conversion error . I think it's good now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select top 100 Expiration , year(Expiration) from CICPROD.ExpiredLots
where year(cast(Expiration as date)) = 2017
```

Comment: I tried that it still throws the error. It could be becuase the source code for that field is an alphanumeric field, which is converted into a date field.